# Python: Desktop UI for my python script

Tags: python

Im new to python and want to create a GUI front-end (desktop, rather than web) for my python script. The script essentially parses XML files and runs various searches over the contents (eg. accepts regex searches from the user, returns results etc).
It works well on the command line but I want to present a more user friendly interface.
There seems to be a lot of options out there - http://docs.python.org/faq/gui.html
Or should I look elsewhere? 
Can someone recommend a GUI toolkit for Python?
Cheers.

Comment: I recommend searching for older questions on this topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend using one of [Tkinter](http://docs.python.org/library/tkinter.html), [wxPython](http://www.wxPython.org) or [PyQt](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/software/pyqt/intro). They are all equally suitable for a simple task. My personal favorite is Tkinter because I think it is the simplest way to get started. However, any of those would make a fine choice.

Comment: Cheers. Tkinter looks ideal for my project. Found an excellent guide here - [link](http://www.tkdocs.com/tutorial/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

[PyQt](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/software/pyqt/intro) is great, although it's on `GPL`. There is also [PySide](http://www.pyside.org/) alternative on `LGPL`.

You can also try [wxPython](http://www.wxpython.org/) or [PyGTK](http://www.pygtk.org/) if you don't like `Qt` for some reason. There is also gui library in python standard library called [Tkinter](http://docs.python.org/library/tkinter.html), but I haven't used it and don't have any experience with it.

Comment: PyQt being GPL doesn't really matter since you're not including PyQt binaries (usually) with your app. The user just has to download qt.

Comment: Maybe you are right, I don't exactly know how `GPL` behaves is such situation. I always thought, that if you develop something based on `PyQt`, you need to make it GPL too or pay for the license.

Comment: Haven't heard anything good? Let me be the first to tell you, then: Tkinter is a very powerful, robust, yet easy to use GUI toolkit. It has been around for many years, is highly cross-platform, and relatively recent versions use native widgets on the mac and windows platforms.

Comment: @Bryan Oakley: I have updated my answer. When I said, that I hadn't heard anything good, I didn't mean, that it sucks. I simply haven't heard much about Tkinter at all. Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://wiki.python.org/moin/GuiProgramming) is a page on the Python wiki with some fifty options.